# What are snares?

Tags: make-no-wonder

In [Make No Wonder](http://www.matthewhollett.com/wonder/index.php), boughs say that they can be used to make snares, but I can't figure out how. I've tried getting a bunch of boughes, wood, birch, and charcoal, since those seem to be the only things without all of their uses listed, but nothing new to craft shows up. What are snares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snares take one bough and one wire, which you can find on a downed plane. Then you can place the snare between two trees, wait a while, and come back to a caught rabbit, which you can eat.

Comment: If you walk over a snare before it has a rabbit you will destroy the snare without getting resources back, so make sure there's a rabbit in it first!